# MATLAB plot of a vector on a specific range

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I need to know how can i plot a vector over a specific interval?
I'm using that to highlight this interval, by plotting the vector values with a different color.
So Eventually, i will need to plot the vector as it is first with blue color for example, and then plot that specific interval with red color.
Thanks for your time,
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = 0:0.01:8*pi;
y = sin(t);
```

If you want to plot a specific `t` interval in red then:

```
ind = t>2 & t<6;
plot(t,y);
hold on
plot(t(ind), y(ind), 'r')
```

If you want to plot a specific `y` interval in red then:

```
ind = y>0.5 & y<0.8;
plot(t,y);
hold on
plot(t(ind), y(ind), 'r')
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, what about if my input that i want to plot is an EEG signal for example? should i create the time vector myself?

Comment: If you just have a `y` vector and are plotting like `plot(y)` then make `t = numel(y)`

Comment: For the time vector you need to know the sample frequency.