# How can I plot part of a simple vector?

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I've got the following vector and plot it from index 1 to 11:

```
a = [1 2 5 4 5 4 2 3 7 1 5];
plot(a);
```

How can I plot only part of this vector? like from index 3 to index 7. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26103811/4122028) but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62838-how-to-plot-portion-of-a-vector-in-matlab?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1 2 5 4 5 4 2 3 7 1 5];
plot(a(3:7));
```